# current timeZone of country from country name(swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift3, timezone

can anyone help me how do I get a current timezone of a particular country..
I am getting list of a countries by this code,

```
let locale = NSLocale.current
let unsortedCountries = NSLocale.isoCountryCodes.map {   locale.localizedString(forRegionCode: $0)! }
let  sortedCountries = unsortedCountries.sorted() as NSArray
print(sortedCountries) // list of countries
```

now I only have country name but i want the current timezone of a particular country (swift 3)

P.S : I am displaying list of countries in tableView and on select of particular cell it should display the current timeZone of that country

Thank You in advance

Comment: Some countries have more than one time zone (the USA, for example.) How are you going to deal with that?

Comment: yes exactly thts my point have  u any idea how do i implement that ..?

Comment: @the4kman  suggest me if have any idea

Comment: Don't use Foundation data types when they have native Swift alternatives. Use `Locale` and `Array`. Moreover, what you are asking for makes no sense. How would you display a single timezone for countries that have several time zones? Please specify what is it you are actually trying to achieve. Countries and time zones have no one-to-one relation, so you should rethink your issue.

Comment: To get current time zone use .local in swift 3

Comment: @chetu not current timezone I want selected country's current timezone

Comment: @Tech - What are you really trying to do? When the user selects "USA", for example, do you want to show the First (or Eastern-most) Time Zone? Or the Last (Western-most) Time Zone? Or do you want to display a List of Time Zones if the country has multiple Time Zones?

Comment: @DonMag For example I want to display a list of available time zones for the concrete country